# Как правильно изучать внутренне устройство интерпетатора?

Tags: python, python-c-api

Хочу изучить внутреннее устройство python`a ?
С чего начать ? Как систематизировать информацию что откуда исходит ?
Или тупо читать код ?

Comment: прочитать все РЕР'ы с дискуссиями не предлагать ?

Comment: начни с изучения языка `c`

Comment: Читать код, да. Объем кода самого интерпретатора не такой уж большой. В библиотеку можно не лезть сразу. Просмотреть для начала `op`-коды.